# iOS-style PageCapture app for OSx?

Tags: macos

I like the iOS PageCapture [here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/page-capture/id370145558?mt=8). I want to find it for Desktop. Where can I find such whole-browser-page-screenshotting app for OSx?

Comment: "If you use a mac, but don't like the command line then you may want to try Paparazzi or Little Snapper.
If you use linux you may be more interested in khtml2png, Matt Biddulph's Mozilla screenshot script or Roland Tapken's QT Webkit script." Webkit2png -app explaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paparazzi isn't a good app. I used it and it didn't work or was very slow to load.

I use a lot Layers Shot and W3Capture, they save the multiple pages or sites and also capture ones whole pages. Layers save as PDF, PNG, TIFF or PSD file. W3Capture, as PDF (separated pages) and PNG (one whole page). I also used a lot Web Slices (**free**), a sites sncreenshot app.

Go to the Mac App Store, search the apps and follow the apps:
(I can't pots more than two hyperlinks)
1) Layers Shot
2) Web Slices

Out of Mac App Store, W3Capture's link: 
http://www.bitsdujour.com/software/wcapture/

More apps that I didn't test yet:
Lightshot Screenshot (it's in Mac App Store and it is **free**)

I hope this answer help you. Good luck with these apps!

Comment: ...now able add link? Thank you for the answer and welcome :)

Comment: @hhh try the hyperlinks:<br/>

Layers Shot: https://itunes.apple.com/be/app/layers-shots/id421247999?mt=12<br/>

Web Slices: https://itunes.apple.com/be/app/web-slices-site-snapshots/id558319027?mt=12

Lightshot: https://itunes.apple.com/be/app/lightshot-screenshot/id526298438?mt=12

Comment: Thank you, I wish there was something like WebSlices but more stable (+PDF-export etc) -- ideal app for monitoring project -pages under development, pretty cool snapshots.

Comment: W3Capture and Layers Shot support the PDF. One tip, when you screenshot a whole site from these two apps, as PNG or PSD, and open one image PNG or PSD, with Preview.app and export it as PDF. Another tip, with Preview, you can cut, crop and delete the parts of the page. If you want to screenshot the multiples wholes sites, just use W3Capture and save as PNG.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Paparazzi!](http://derailer.org/paparazzi/). It sounds like that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use OSx apps, go with your browser -- use Awesome Screenshot Capture -plugin in Chromium [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-screenshot-captur/alelhddbbhepgpmgidjdcjakblofbmce). It has also annotating -features.